# UIDatePickers height is not animating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, autolayout

I have a `UIDatePicker` in a static `UITableViewCell` with auto layout applied (to the `datePicker`). The `datePicker` is hidden until a `button` is selected. When the `button` is selected, the `datePicker` becomes visible, and the `cells` height gets bigger.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if (self.datePickerView.hidden == YES) {
            return 252 - self.datePickerView.bounds.size.height;
        }
        else return 252;
    }
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150;
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (IBAction)datePicker:(id)sender
{
    if (self.datePickerView.hidden == YES)
    {
        [self.datePickerView setHidden:NO];

        CGFloat originalHeight = 162;
        [self.datePickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.datePickerView.frame.origin.x, self.datePickerView.frame.origin.y, self.datePickerView.frame.size.width, 0)];
        [UIDatePicker animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(){
            [self.datePickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.datePickerView.frame.origin.x, self.datePickerView.frame.origin.y, self.datePickerView.frame.size.width, originalHeight)];
        }];
    } else {

        [self.datePickerView setHidden:YES];
    }
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

When the `button` gets selected, the `cells` height is animated, but the `datePicker` isn't. It just appears, and gets in the way of everything until the `cell` is finished animating.

How can I get the `datePicker` to animate its height, so it should animate together with the `cell`?

Comment: The problem is probably that a date picker's height is not up to you. You really can't change it, in general; so that's probably why can't animate a change in it.

Comment: Good point!! So do you have any other solution? Maybe a workaround?

Comment: You could sub-class UITableViewCell to allow for a cell that contains a UIDatePicker that animates simultaneously alongside the cell resizing.

One question that I have is: Why are you attempting to set the UIDatePicker frame when you are also using Autolayout?

Comment: I did that so it should animate its height

Comment: Listen to what @MikeBell is telling you. If you are using autolayout you must not change the frame of anything. You must change the constraints. You can animate a change in constraints. Maybe that would solve it?

Comment: Tried it, but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Updating frames would not work with auto-layout. you'll have to update your constraint to do the animation.

In your case, you should have separate cell for your datePickerview and insert/ remove the cell from your tableview in order to hide and show the pickerview with animation.

[Edited]
Sample Code here: http://www.filedropper.com/tableviewsample

Comment: Can I do that with static cells?

Comment: yes but dequeue the cell would also work and reuse the same cell

Comment: I can remove the cell, (because I know the indexPath,) but how can I insert the cell without knowing the indexPath?